# What's Wrong With My Gallery Code

Tags: html

I'm building a website for a class and I need some help with creating a gallery of pictures.
The gallery comes up but the pictures don't. I know it has something to do with the source but i'm not sure what precisely it is.  Here's my code:

```
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_Crisis.jpg">
      <img src="img_Crisis.jpg" alt="CHRYSALIDOCARPUS LUTESCENS potted plant" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Plant For Sale</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_Cyrus.jpg">
      <img src="img_Cyrus.jpg" alt="CYCAS REVOLUTA" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Plant For Sale</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_Kard.jpg">
      <img src="img_Kard.jpg" alt="Kardemumma" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Plant For Sale</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_Mandel.jpg">
      <img src="img_Mandel.jpg" alt="Mandel" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Plant For Sale</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div style="padding:6px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Kindly show a working example

Comment: can you update this in fiddle

Comment: Try with relative path like images/img_kard.jpg.
Please provide your folder structure. That will help to answer your question.

Comment: That issue is only related with the path of image. Please give me your page path image location. Local host path will be ok. I will evaluate page and image path. You can do one more thing if you inspect browser for the http request and if it show 404 with image name . Then it is sure that image path are wrong.